# Which Mercurial hook should I use for bugzilla extension on a server repository?

Tags: mercurial

I would like to know how I can make use of the hooks to control the incoming push/commit.

The situation is that I have a centralized repositories server running Mercurial in Linux and  all of the developers use TortoiseHg in Windows.

Also, we have use the Mercurial Bugzilla extenstion to link with the repositories, so that when a "hg commit" is issued in the Linux host, the comments can be updated the Bugzilla DB. It works fine in the Linux host itself, however, how I can get this work for those TortoiseHg clients?

In the Linux host itself, I can make use of the hooks to control the commit statement.

```
[hooks]
commit.bugzilla = python:hgext.bugzilla.hook
```

Should I use incoming.bugzilla instead?

Can I setup this environment without ask each TortoiseHg client to configure its own hgrc?

please help

- paul

Comment: -1 because the correct configuration is clearly documented [on the extension wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugzillaExtension). Also you already suggest the correct answer yourself. Did you bother to try before asking?

Comment: -1 because above, and for poor question title as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `incoming` for the hook.

Committing is a local operation, and when you have a central server configuration nobody ever commits to it. People only share already-committed changesets by pushing, which triggers the `incoming` hook.

The correct configuration is documented [on the extension wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugzillaExtension).

Comment: yes. we should using incoming, however, it doesn't work. anyone has tried this before?

Comment: I use the `incoming` hook to auto-update my website when I push new changes to its repository, and it works fine. What if you add an incoming hook that just echoes a test string (`incoming.test = echo testing`), then push to the repo, do you see the test string in the push output as "remote:" line? That means the hook is called.